# Where are Linux 2 .ebextension files written on the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ebextensions

I want to SSh into the EC2 instance and see my config files for the .ebextension for my Elastic Beanstalk deployment.  This is in Linux 2.   I can SSH into the instance fine.  I can find the platform/hooks directory, but I am at a loss where to see my config files.

Comment: By default "dot" files are not visible.  It should be at the root of your deployment.  Did you do an `ls -a`?

Comment: I put a pwd command in my file and figured out it was being written to /var/app/staging/.ebextensions.